# If Paul says Jesus is Joel's YHVH in [Romans 10:13] and John says Jesus is Elohim of Genesis [John 1:3], Jesus continues to create evil [Isaiah 45:7]?

Tags: john, jesus, romans, isaiah

**Since Jesus is Yoel's YHVH to Paul** : [Romans 10:13] " For whosoever shall call upon the name of the LORD shall be saved. " - referencing Yoel 3:5 (MT) | Joel 2:32 (KJV),

**And Jesus is the Elohim of Genesis to John** : [John 1:3] "Through him all things were made; without him nothing was made that has been made." ,

**Then Jesus continues to create Evil : [Isaiah 45:7]?**

[Yeshayahu יְשַׁעְיָ֣הוּ | Isaiah 45:7] "Who forms light and creates darkness, Who makes peace and creates evil ; I am YHVH, Who makes all these." ( יוֹצֵ֥ר אוֹר֙ וּבוֹרֵ֣א חֹ֔שֶׁךְ עֹשֶׂ֥ה שָׁל֖וֹם וּב֣וֹרֵא רָ֑ע אֲנִ֥י יְהֹוָ֖ה עֹשֶׂ֥ה כָל־אֵֽלֶּה )

**Does Jesus create evil, or was the prophet Yeshayahu speaking falsely?**

Comment: It's as if you are injecting a heretical belief (denial of Jesus' divinity) into a common question about Isaiah 45:7

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 - No. | For Love of wisdom from the New Testament & Gospels, I hope to better understand Jesus as related to us through Isaiah. - Thank you very much for sharing your insight regarding this bible study.

Comment: No, this is a trollish question eliciting disputations about the trinity and the nature of evil, which are theological questions, not exegetical questions. Chidah, you should do a bit better. -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Hebrew, "evil" (Heb. *ra*) had a much wider range of meaning than simply moral evil, but also meant natural evil — calamity, disaster, and ills.

In this context, *evil* is opposite of *peace* (or alternatively, *wellbeing*) (just as *light* is of *dark*), and thus demonstrates the kind of evil meant, namely, calamity — not malice.

God is not the author of evil doing or evil, since evil is defined against God's eternal nature (i.e. good), and not against a creature, and has no essence or existence outside of and absent such a definition.

For example, a priest will examine a beast as to "whether it be good or bad" and estimate a price for its ritual redemption:

> **Leviticus 27:12** And the priest shall evaluate it, whether it be good or **bad**: according as the priest shall determine, so shall the price be.

So yes, God does create evil in the sense that He is the cause both of calamity and prosperity and peace. But He does not cause, as in directly will (although He certainly allows) evil.

An example from the New Testament is where Jesus punishes a false prophetess with the death of her children.

> **Revelation 2:18-23** And to the angel of the church of Thyatira write: These things saith the Son of God, who hath his eyes like to a flame of fire, and his feet like to fine brass. 19 I know thy works, and thy faith, and thy charity, and thy ministry, and thy patience, and thy last works which are more than the former. 20 But I have against thee a few things: because thou sufferest the woman Jezabel, who calleth herself a prophetess, to teach, and to seduce my servants, to commit fornication, and to eat of things sacrificed to idols. 21 And I gave her a time that she might repent, and she will not repent of her fornication. 22 Behold, I will cast her into a bed: except they repent from their deeds. 23 And **I will kill her children with death, and all the churches shall know that I am he that searcheth the reins and hearts, and I will give to every one of you according to your works.**

Cf. Ps. 7:10; Jer. 17:10; 1 Ki 8:39.

Certainly this is a natural evil, but it isn't evil as God  to punish evildoers. Cf. Gn. 38:7.

Comment: Would "Death" be a natural רָע 'disaster' that Jesus creates only for evildoers?

Comment: Ultimately, now that we live in a world wherein the consequences of our father's first sin are felt and inescapable, natural evil cannot be avoided (that is to say, it's not always as a punishment that people suffer these ills). "For God created man incorruptible, and to the image of his own likeness he made him. But by the envy of the devil, death came into the world: and they follow him that are of his side." Death cannot hurt those who take the offer of the Redeemer, since it represents a mere step into the 'next life' cocolloquially speaking, the world to come (*olam haba*).

Answer (score 1):

Let's see the context in NIV Isaiah 45:

> 6 so that from the rising of the sun
> to the place of its setting
> people may know there is none besides me.
> I am the Lord, and there is no other.

From the east to the west, there is only one true God, the Lord. Then comes verse 7:

```
I              form    the light    and create   darkness,
I              bring   prosperity   and create   disaster;
I, the Lord,   do      all these things.
```

Light || prosperity.
Darkness || disaster.

King James Bible:

> I form the light, and create darkness:
> I make peace, and create evil:
> I the LORD do all these things.

The operative word is H7451. NIV translates it as *disaster*; KJV uses *evil*. In either case, the parallelism structure shows that light brings prosperous results while darkness brings evil disastrous results.
In this structure, H7451 (evil/disaster) is not the cause but the result.

Benson explains:

> Isaiah 45:7. I form the light, and create darkness, &c. — **All men’s comforts and calamities come from my hand.**

That's the point, that God is all-powerful.

The cultural context at Isaiah's time was Persia and Magian beliefs.

> “It was the great principle of the Magian religion, which prevailed in Persia in the time of Cyrus, and in which probably he was educated, that there are two supreme, coeternal, and independent causes, always acting in opposition one to the other; one, the author of all good, the other, of all evil; the good being they called **Light**; the evil being **Darkness**; that, when Light had the ascendant, then good and happiness prevailed among men; when Darkness had the superiority, then evil and misery abounded.

Isaiah wants to show that the Lord is even above these two ultimate Magian causes and it makes better sense to have one omnipotent God.

> All opinion that contradicts the clearest evidence of our reason, which plainly leads us to the acknowledgment of one only Supreme Being, infinitely good as well as powerful. With reference to this absurd opinion, held probably by the person to whom this prophecy is addressed, God, by his prophet, in the most significant terms, asserts his **omnipotence** and absolute supremacy. I am JEHOVAH, and none else; forming light, and creating darkness; making peace, and **creating evil**;

It is in this omnipotent sense that God creates evil disasters.

> I JEHOVAH am the author of all these things.” Declaring that there is no power, either of light or darkness, of good or evil, of happiness or misery, independent of the one supreme God, infinite in power and in goodness.

Comment: Then Isaiah actually enlightens us that Jesus creates "disasters" not evil? - Thanks for sharing your insight, Tony.

Comment: yes, but only in the sense of omnipotence. +1 to your asking this question. I have learned quite a bit from my research into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The broken link to your logic is Isa. 45:7.  Hebrew's way of expressing what is present tense in English is typically to use participles.

> יֹוצֵ֥ר אֹור֙ וּבֹורֵ֣א חֹ֔שֶׁךְ
> עֹשֶׂ֥ה שָׁלֹ֖ום
> וּבֹ֣ורֵא רָ֑ע
> אֲנִ֥י יְהוָ֖ה עֹשֶׂ֥ה כָל־אֵֽלֶּה׃
> (Isa. 45:7, MT-BHS)

What makes sense is translating, "I form light and it creates darkness," because darkness is the lack of light.  Light is photons.  Darkness is nothing, but without the existence of light, darkness is meaningless.  Isaiah wasn't giving a physics lesson.  His point was to express the same relationship in the next clause.

Thus, "I produce well-being and it creates distress/misery/injury/calamity," the opposite of well-being, the absence of well-being, which is only known because of well-being.  The opposite of well-being is not evil.

> רַע S7451 TWOT2191a GK8273126 n.m. Jb 30:26 *evil, distress, misery, injury, calamity*;...
> --
> Brown, F., Driver, S. R., & Briggs, C. A. (1977). Enhanced Brown-Driver-Briggs Hebrew and English Lexicon (p. 948). Oxford: Clarendon Press.

**The answer is that Isa 45:7 isn't referring to evil because evil isn't the opposite of well-being.  Bad things such as calamity and illness are.**

**Appendix**

However, evil is the absence of good.  In a dynamic, rather than a static, world creating good results in the existence of evil.  If people could only do good without a choice, would they really be good or have the ability to learn good.  It would be a morally static choiceless world with no responsibility.

> 4.5.15 (see p. 592). That “sin is a privation, a defect rather than an effect,” may be thus illustrated. Sickness is the mere defect of health; the absence of health. But health is not the mere defect or absence of sickness. Health is the normal and right condition of the body, the positive state having its own positive characteristics. Sickness is the abnormal and wrong condition of the body, which is marked not by a set of positive characteristics antithetic to those of health, but only of negative characteristics which consist in the absence of the positive. For illustration, indigestion is the absence of certain properties that make up digestion, not the presence of certain other properties that make up indigestion. Simply ceasing to digest is indigestion; it is not necessary to introduce some new physical processes in order to indigestion, but merely to stop some old ones. Augustine (Enchiridion 13–14) thus explains the subject: “Every being, even if it be a defective one, insofar as it is a being is good and insofar as it is defective, is evil. Good and evil are contraries, but evil cannot exist without good or in anything that is not good. Good, however, can exist without evil. For a man or an angel can exist without being wicked; but nothing can be wicked except a man or an angel; and so far as he is a man or an angel [i.e., a creature of God] he is good; so far as he is wicked he is an evil. Nothing can be corrupted except what is good, for corruption is nothing else but the destruction of good.”
> --
> Shedd, W. G. T. (2003). Dogmatic theology. (A. W. Gomes, Ed.) (3rd ed., p. 609). Phillipsburg, NJ: P & R Pub.

Comment: I particularly like this answer.